# Longest strict partition of a positive integer?

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

I have just finished my 1st year in Computer Science. Since the holidays began, I've been studying algorithms and different computer science problems.

The following problem has proved quite difficult for me:

*Let there be **N, k** two positive integers. Find the **max k such that (Y1+1)(Y2+1)...(Yk+1) = N**, where the Ys are also positive **distinct** integers;*

Ok, so here was my take on this problem: **1)** Break *N* in prime factors. A simple example: 42 = 2 * 3 * 7. I can already see that "I don't care" about the "+1" inside the paranthesis, since 42 = (1+1) * (2+1) * (6+1), so Y1 = 1, Y2 = 2, Y3 = 6. **2)** But what if the powers of the prime factors are bigger, like: N = 2^3 * 7^2 * 3^6 and so on. Well, now I have many more possibilities to study. For this case, **max k** would be 6, because N = 2^1 * 2^2 * 7^2 * 3^1 * 3^2 * 3^3 = 2 * 4 * 49 * 3 * 9 * 27 = (1+1)*(3+1)*(48+1)(2+1)(8+1)(26+1). I can see that the idea is to **break the power of each prime factor into the longest sum of distinct positive integers**. By longest, I mean to have as many terms as possible in the sum. Because that would give me the most distinct terms in the product of N. The last example: N = 2^(1+2) * 7^2 * 3^(1+2+3) = 2^1 * 2^2 * 7^2 * 3^1 * 3^2 * 3^3 = 2 * 4 * 49 * 3 * 9 * 27 => *max k*  = 6.

I've searched the internet for some time and I've found some very interesting concepts (I actually regretted not doing the math major). One of these concepts is partitions; more exactly, it seems that **I need the longest strict partition of a positive integer** (that is, for every power of the prime factors of N).

Any help (references/notes/suggestions/ other ideas!) would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I forgot to point out that N is no bigger than 10^15. So, I guess that the powers of the prime factors of N shouldn't be that big, right?

Comment: a very similar question : [Finding the largest subset of factors of a number whose product is the number itself](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930162/finding-the-largest-subset-of-factors-of-a-number-whose-product-is-the-number-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\triangle_m \equiv \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ be the $m$-th trangular number, and let $L(n)$ be the number of entries in the longest strict additive partition of the numbers from $1$ to $n$. Then
$$
\triangle_{L(n)} \leq n
$$ 
and $L(n)$ is the largest integer for which that relation holds.  So for example,
$L(8) = 3$ because $\triangle_{3} = 6 \leq 8$ but $\triangle_{4} = 10 >8$.

I have been trying to express $L(n)$ in closed form using expressions involving $\sqrt{2n}$ and floor or ceiling functions, but it does not seem to be easy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! This solves the question. Now I can implement the algorithm. The problem is, I understand now **how** to implement it, but I don't know why this relationship holds :( Is there any good book I can study on partitions? Or multiple books?

Comment: This particular partitioning problem is tractable because the insight that there is no gain in skipping a number solves it immediately. Allowing repeats, the number of ways to partitiion $n$ is the coef. of $z^n$ in $\frac1{(1-z)(1-z^2)(1-z^3)\cdots}$. No closed form for $p(n)$ is known, but interesting facts arise; for example, $p(7n+5) $ is always a multiple of 7. George Andrews "The Theory of Partitions" is a good book in depth, but may be too difficult for you. Concrete Mathematics by Graham and Knuth has good scttered bits on partition numbers.

Comment: remarkable answer in a few lines :) It is efficient to count the number of subsets but there is more headaches to enumerate one of the solutions ( there are a lot of symmetries )

Answer (score 0):

As Mark has already pointed out, $L(n)$ is the largest integer $m$ for which
\begin{align*}
\frac{m(m+1)}{2}&\leq n\\
\iff \left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}&\leq 2n\\
\iff m&\leq \sqrt{2n+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}
It follows that $L(n)=\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor$.