# Finding the largest subset of factors of a number whose product is the number itself

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

Given a positive integer $x$, find $k$ distinct positive integers $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k$ such that
$$
x = \prod_{i=1}^k(1+y_i)
$$
The problem is to pick the $y$'s so that $k$ is as large as possible.

Now, if the restriction of distinctness of $y$'s is removed, the problem becomes really simple. Let
$$
x = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}
$$
be the prime factorization of $x$ ($p_i$ are prime numbers), then the answer is simply $k=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$.

But I cannot seem to figure out how to solve this if $y_i$ are required to be distinct.

One approach I tried was to simply greedily pick the factors(excluding $1$) of $x$ in ascending order.

To illustrate, for $x=36$, the factors are $2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36$.

1. I choose $2$ because $2$ divides $36$.
2. I choose $3$ because it divides $18$ ($=\frac{36}{2}$).
3. Next I skip $4$ as it does not divide $6$ ($=\frac{36}{2\times3}$).
4. Finally pick $6$ which divides 6.

I end up with $k=3$. But I couldn't prove that this algorithm is correct.

EDIT: I am primarily interested in finding $k$, the size of the largest subset.

---

My initial guess for the solution to this problem if $x$ is the power of a prime seems to be true. Let
$$
x = p^a
$$
Consider the following problem:

Find number of integer solutions of:
$$
n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_k = a \, (n_1 > n_2 > \dots > n_k > 0)
$$
Let $m_k = n_k, m_i = n_i -n_{i+1} (i\neq k)$
Then that problem can be rewritten as the number of integer solutions of:
$$
m_1 + 2m_2 + \dots + km_k = a \, (m_i > 0)
$$

which is the coefficient of $x^a$ in
$$
\frac{x^{(1+2+\dots+k)}}{(1-x)(1-x^2)\dots(1-x^k)}
$$
which is non-zero iff $\frac{k(k+1)}{2} \leq a$

---

Going back to the original problem, this means that if $x=p^a$ then $k = \lfloor{\frac{\sqrt{1+8a}-1}{2}\rfloor}$ and $y_i = p^i-1, 1 \leq i < k$ and $y_k=p^{a-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}-1$

So for $x=8192=2^{13}$, $k = 4, y_1 = 1, y_2 = 3, y_3 = 7, y_4 = 127$. Note that the choice of $y$ is not unique. $y_1 = 1, y_2 = 3, y_3 = 15, y_4 = 63$ is also a legitimate solution.

As @Wore mentions in the comments how to we extend this to $x$ when it is not the power of a prime?

Comment: By simplifying the problem and assuming $n=p^m$ for some prime $p$, what you are trying to do requires to know the length of a maximal proper partition of $m$ (the lenght of a maximal sequence $(m_1,\ldots,m_k)$ such that $m_1<m_2<\ldots<m_k$ and $m_1+\ldots+m_k=m$. I am not sure if this helps or not, since I don't know much about partitions

Comment: @Wore Yes, that works only if $x$ has one distinct prime factor. In fact, in that case $m_i=i$ (except $m_k$, of course).

Comment: I think what you meant is that in this case $y_i=p^{m_i}-1$, for $i=1,\ldots,k$, but note that this is not an answer unless you know how to calculate the maximal length of a proper partition of $m$. Do you know?

Comment: I mean that the maximal partition is probably simply, $1, 2, \dots , l-1, m - \left(\frac{l(l-1)}{2}\right)$ $l$ is the largest integer such that $m - \left(\frac{l(l-1)}{2}\right) > 0$

Comment: In that case there might be a problem because you could have $m-\left(\frac{l(l-1)}{2}\right)$ equal to one of $1,2,\ldots,l-1$. However, if you have such maximal partitions, and $x=p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_r^{m_r}$, it seems that applying the method to each $p_i^{m_i}$, would solve the problem, of course combining at the end the remaining factors $p_i^{m_i-\left(\frac{l(l-1)}{2}\right)}$ by applying the same method to powers of $p_ip_j$ with $p_i\neq p_j$.

Comment: @igael I think it is sum, $x= 40 = 2^3\times 5^1 = 2 \times2 \times2 \times5$, so $k = 3 + 1 = 4$

Comment: nice question ... are you mainly interested by the count or by an enumeration method ?

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in the count $k$. Though, getting the $y_i$ would be awesome.

Comment: Given how complicated the answer is when $n$ is just a prime power, I doubt there is any particularly nice answer in general

Comment: @EricWofsey, please see my edit.

Comment: What do you mean when you write, "this approach does not seem to work"? Do you mean that you have an example where this method gives the wrong answer? Or do you just mean you can't prove it always works?

Comment: I couldn't prove it's correct. I will edit it for clarity, sorry about that.

Comment: The numbers are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A086435 but there's not much further information there. There is a link to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UnorderedFactorization.html where some references to the literature are given, but I haven't followed them up to see whether they discuss this problem or one of the related problems in the mathworld essay.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The links are very informative, thanks for that and also for disproving the greedy algorithm.

Comment: It is finally a very difficult question with the superposition of 2 models ( partition and stars and bars) + nested pairing ,  which are not very easy to implement. I tried some models without success, including one who seems a lot to what Ross was speaking ( I failed with the unit factor status ) ... Then , I'll wait for an expert script answer ...

Comment: @igael Are you saying that you found a counter example to Ross's algorithm?

Comment: I got an algorithm working by minimal fusions. Must find time to implement it and to check the bounds ... A such ulgy script will be difficult to express in natural langage. I tried during a long time without success...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try a greedy approach. I haven't developed it into an algorithm, but it is a thought.  If you factor $x=p^aq^br^c \ldots$ into prime powers, the answer will only depend on the multiset $\{a,b,c,\ldots \}$. The primes will not matter.  The first factors to claim are the primes dividing $x$, specifically $p,q,r,\ldots$  The next cheapest factors are of the form $pq$ or $p^2$. You don't want to use the square for primes you don't have many of.  Next try $p^2q$ where you consider primes with low exponents expensive and don't square them.  This seems a problem that is very hard to program, but will be obvious to a human as long as the number of prime powers is not too large.

Comment: Let's define the index of a number $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$ to be $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_r$. Then I think you want to take all the factors of $n$ with index 1, then as many factors of index 2 as possible, then as many of index 3 (that is, of types $p^3$, $p^2q$, and $pqr$) as possible, and so on.

Comment: How does one prove this works?

Comment: @Priyatham:  it seems "obvious" that it does, as you use up as few of the prime factors as possible at each stage.  That is why I called it a greedy algorithm.  I worry about what happens if there are more factors of one prime than the others.  The examples I have tried do not cause a problem, though.  If $n=2^{12}3^4$ you start with $2,3,4,6,9$ and can't split the last $256$ as $16,16$, but you can do $8,32$

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can't always take all the factors of $n$ with index $1$. For instance, consider the case where $n=p^2q$; the only valid solutions are $\{p, pq\}$ and $\{p^2, q\}$, neither of which has all the atoms.

Comment: @Steven, right – I should have said, take as many of index 1 as possible, then as many of index 2 as possible, and so on, where "as possible" means "as you can without making it impossible to complete the factorization".

Answer (score 0):

Deleted.

Let $x=p_1^{m_1}\cdots p_n^{m_n}=2^5 3^4 5^5$
Loop through the list of all divisors of $x$ that are $<p_n^2$, if $d_k | x$ increase counter by one and set $x= x/d_k$ , else continue

Here is the proof:

Suppose $d=\{ d_{n_1}, \ldots d_{n_k} \}$ is the list constructed by this greedy algorithm. Suppose there exists a bigger list $d'=\{ d_{m_1}, \ldots d_{m_{k'}} \}$ containing $j$ equal enteries. That would mean the divisors form the list $d$ can transform to more enteries that are not in $d$. Since the algorithm is greedy, ANY refinement ( *using their factors to construct new enteries*) of those divisors will give ones already contained in $d$ (*because the greedy algorithm already processed any smaller divisors*), a contradiction, on the other way any coarse transformation will give less new enteries than we started, also a contradiction.

Comment: This is the exact algorithm I wrote in my question, right? I did it for $36$ as an example.

Comment: Unless you can prove the correctness, I am sorry to say that this is nothing new.

Comment: whoops sorry then

Comment: If you're ordering divisors by their usual integer order (instead of some ordering based on their prime factorization), the greedy algorithm does not work.  For instance, consider $x=p^{10}q^2r^3$.  If $p\ll q\ll r$, you will pick $p, p^2,p^3,p^4,q,qr,r^2$.  But you can do better by picking $p,p^2,p^3,q,pq,r,pr,p^2r$.

Comment: I agree with you, it does depend on ordering of divisors.

Comment: Another example, with two primes: if $n=p^{10}q^{10}$ with $q>p^4$, then picking the smallest available divisor at each stage gets you eight ($p,p^2,p^3,p^4,q,q^2,q^3,q^4$), but you can get nine as $p,q,p^2,pq,q^2,p^3,p^2q,pq^2,q^3$.